# Selects dinámicos, No selecciona correctamente el valor desde jquery

Tags: html, jquery, laravel

**Problema:**
Tengo una tabla en la cual se registran los valores tomados en una muestra, los datos tomados son: lugar de cultivo, linea de cultivo, unidades, etc.

Al momento de registrar estos datos no tengo problemas estos se guardan el la BD correctamente, pero cuando quiero modificar los registros ya guardados estos no se muestran de la misma forma en los que se encuentran en la base de datos, sin embargo los valores provenientes si están correctos. **Esto me ocurre con los `input tipo select`** los demás `input` se cargan con los datos correspondientes.

En la siguiente imagen lado izquierdo (**Al crear**) muestra el orden de los datos en que los guardo, en la misma imagen (**Al modificar**) lado derecho es la forma en que se muestran al pulsar en modificar planilla, (esta abre una ventana modal en la cual se encuentra la tabla), acá es donde ocurre el inconveniente con los `input select` y no selecciona los que tuvieran que estar seleccionados.

[image: img]

**Codigo HTML tabla de datos**

```
<table id="tbl-planilla-siembra" class="table table-bordered">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Centro</th>
        
        <th><i id="icon-add-rows-planilla-siembra" class="fas fa-plus-circle fa-2x" style="color:green; cursor: pointer;"></i></th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>                            
    <tr>
        <td>
            <!--Input select de centro, se llena de forma dinamica al seleccionar un proveedor-->
            {!! Form::select('Pla_ID_Centro[]', [], null, ['class' => 'form-control Pla_ID_Centro', 'placeholder' => 'Seleccione']) !!}
        </td>
        
        <td>
            <i class="icon-sub-row-planilla-siembra far fa-trash-alt fa-2x" style="color: red; cursor: pointer;"></i>
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>                        
</table>
```

**Codigo JS funcion que obtiene y genera los registros en la tabla**

```
function get_planilla_proveedor(boton, input_hidden, modal, label){
boton.attr('disabled',true);
btn_text = boton.html();
boton.html('<i class="fas fa-spinner fa-spin"></i>');
var datos = '_token='+$('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')+'&ID_Proveedor='+boton.attr('value');
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: url+'/abastecimiento/proveedores/get_planilla_siembra',
    data: datos,
    success: function(retorna) {

var tabla_tbody = $('#tbl-planilla-siembra tbody');
var tabla_tbody_tr = $('#tbl-planilla-siembra tbody tr');
var tabla_tbody_tr_first = $('#tbl-planilla-siembra tbody tr:first');

$('#tbl-planilla-siembra tbody tr').remove();

$.each(retorna, function(indice, centro){
    $.each(centro.planilla_siembras,function(indice_centro, planilla){

        tabla_tbody_tr_first.find('.Pla_ID_Centro option[value='+ planilla.ID_Centro +"]").attr("selected",true);

        tabla_tbody_tr_first.find('.Pla_ID_Origen option[value='+ planilla.ID_Origen_Semilla +"]").attr("selected",true);


        tabla_tbody.append(tabla_tbody_tr_first.clone());
    });
});
   $('select').removeClass('chzn-done').removeAttr("id").css("display", "block").next().remove();
        $('select').chosen({
            inherit_select_classes: true,
            no_results_text: "No hay resultados para:",
            width: "inherit"//para modal
        })
        boton.html(btn_text);
        boton.attr('disabled',false);
        input_hidden.val(boton.attr('value'));
        label.html(boton.parents('tr').find("td").eq(1).html());
        modal.modal('show');
    },
    error:function(retorna){
        if(retorna.responseJSON.message == "Unauthenticated."){
            location.reload();
        }
        console.log(retorna);
        alerta_error(retorna);
        boton.html(btn_text);
        boton.attr('disabled',false);
    }
});
}
```

**Datos que trae la variable `retorna`:**

[image: img datos]

Comment: No entendí tu pregunta. ¿Qué es lo que se debe seleccionar? ¿Qué es lo que se está seleccionando?  ¿Cuál es el código HTML?  ¿No estarás dando `id` duplicado a los elementos?

Comment: Saludos @A.Cedano, En la imagen primera (**Al crear**) selecciono valores diferentes para los `select`, los guardo y todo bien, pero al editarlos (**Al modificar**) y cargarlos con `js` no muestra seleccionados los que seleccione al momento de crearlos

Comment: Sugiero que [edites la pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/219750/edit), explicando mejor las cosas y poniendo el código HTML. Realmente, el problema no se entiende y tu explicación es muy pobre. A veces se hace difícil encontrar la solución por la dificultad de explicar el problema. En tu caso puede que esté ocurriendo eso. Es saludable verbalizar el problema, te invito a hacerlo.

Comment: @A.Cedano, he modificado mi pregunta espero sea mas clara

Comment: buenas,estoy viendo que cuando haces un foreach al resultado,estas indicando que seleccione un valor que no veo en el Json, `ID_Origen_Semilla`